# Extracting data from text file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-io, foreach

I'm currently extracting data from a text file and then attempting to perform an action for each entry in the text file. See code below.

```
$Employees = Get-Content C:\User\Documents\UserWorkstations.txt
Foreach($name in $Employees)
{
  ping $name
}
```

After running my script it does not extract data from the text file and I get the following output:

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:
```

Comment: ... this is probably not a very good title

Comment: How's this Christian?

Comment: Try to be more specific and post an example coherent example. Your example uses a foreach statement loop while the error shows that the foreach-object was used.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\User\Documents\UserWorkstations.txt' |
    Foreach-Object {
        Write-Host ('Pinging {0}' -f $_)
        ping $_
    }
```

Comment: This would be my route, I prefer to pipe into the foreach, and PowerShell seems to agree... Although as I recall *| ` <newline> foreach...* also works better still.